# Combinatorial optimization - different value per container

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

Given a set of n distinct items and k containers, each of n/k size, how do you distribute the items into the containers all the while maximizing value stored? The catch is, each item has a different value for each container.

Trying to wrap my head around this longer than feels reasonable. So this is clearly a combinatorial optimization problem, but it's not simple profit maximization (or is it?) nor knapsack or others that came to mind, but all my attempts to categorize it further or solve it other than ugly brute-force way have been in vain.
(It's an exercise from a foreign Algorithms textbook, Dynamic Programming section, alas as is often the textbook way, without any explanation).

Comment: If all of the items have unit size, then this problem can be solved with a maximum-weight matching algorithm, which makes its placement in the dynamic programming section sort of curious. In any case, the DP would seem to have a large number of states.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realize it's essentially a complete bipartite graph. This makes me wonder about the Dynamic programming aspect, too... The exercise demands an O(n^4) solution, and I don't think it's expected of the reader to devise the Hungarian algorithm by himself. Also any article I come across about the Assignment problem only ever assumes workers=tasks. But this is the same thing, except you need multiple workers for each task.

Comment: @user742925: Well, you *could* create a bipartite graph with the n items in one part and the n *positions in* containers in the other, and just remember which container each position belongs in.  But my feeling is that this is not the best way to solve it, since it will admit a huge number ((n/k)!^k) of equally-good solutions.

Comment: Probably good approximation is to do n/k maximum matching. Each matching matches (the best) k workers to k tasks.